# hover on different elements (CSS only solution)

Tags: html, css, hover, pseudo-element

I'm having troubles on applying a hover effect on different HTML elements, such as changing the color of a DIV's border and it's parents DIV's background color.

My HTML code looks like this:

```
<div id="time-later">
   <div class="time-arrow"></div>
   <p>later</p>
</div>
```

The matching CSS code:

```
#time-later {
   height: 35px;
   width: calc(25% - (15px/4));
}

#time-later p {
   display: block;
   width: calc(100% - 14.5px);
   margin-right: 14.5px;
}

#time-later .time-arrow {
   float: right;
   width: 0;
   height: 0;
   border-top: 17.5px solid transparent;
   border-left: 14.5px solid green;
   border-bottom: 17.5px solid transparent;
   z-index: 1;
}
```

some styling

```
#time-later p {
   text-align: center;
   line-height: 35px;
   background-color: green;
}

#time-later p:hover {
   background-color: red;
}

#time-later p:active {
   color: #FFF;
   background-color: gray;
}
```

When I move the mouse over the #time-later element I want the background of the p-element and the border of the .arrow-element to be colored in the same color.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z0vm0nm4/1/)

[image: hover effect on different elements]

Is there any CSS-only solution to achieve something like this? I know it would be easier to place an image instead, but I'm searching for a CSS-only solution. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Move `:hover` and `:active` to the parent element, then target the children as follows:

**[Example Here](http://jsfiddle.net/z0vm0nm4/3/)**

```css
#time-later:hover > p { background-color: red; }
#time-later:hover > .time-arrow { border-left-color: red; }

#time-later:active > p { background-color: gray; color: white; }
#time-later:active > .time-arrow { border-left-color: gray; }
```

Answer (score 0):

## [JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/mosibohoke/1/edit?html,css,output)

Through modify their parent pseudo-style to handle what you want.

## css

```
#time-later:hover p{
   background-color: red;
}
#time-later:hover .time-arrow{
   border-left: 14.5px solid red;
}     
#time-later:active p {
   color: #FFF;
   background-color: gray;
}
#time-later:active .time-arrow{
  border-left: 14.5px solid gray;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

like this? http://jsfiddle.net/z0vm0nm4/1/

```
  #time-later:hover p{
       background-color: red;
    }
    #time-later:hover .time-arrow {
       border-left: 14.5px solid red;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do hover on div
example:

```
div#time-later:hover .time-arrow{
   border-top: 17.5px solid transparent;
   border-left: 14.5px solid background:tan;
   border-bottom: 17.5px solid transparent;
}

div#time-later:hover p{
   background:tan;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this one, worked for me:

```
/* some stylings */

#time-later p {
   text-align: center;
   line-height: 35px;
   background-color: green;
}

#time-later:hover p {
   background-color: red;
}

#time-later:active p {
   color: #FFF;
   background-color: gray;
}

#time-later:hover .time-arrow {
   border-left: 14.5px solid red;
}

#time-later:active .time-arrow {
border-left: 14.5px solid gray;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/h50L9noy/